# 'hover over' popup with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have implemented an informational popup in a python app using a Tkinter Menu widget.  I have a Text widget on a canvas in the root window. I created a Menu widget that has root as its parent.  When I detect a mouse hover over the text widget I post the popup menu with menuWidget.post(). When I get a leave event from the text widget my intention was to have the popup disappear by calling menuWidget.unpost(), only the popup menu does not disappear until I click elsewhere outside the text widget.

First, is this a sane method for implementing an informational popup? And can anyone tell me why the popup menu won't disappear?

Answer (score 3):

This is not the right way to do an informational popup. On the Mac and on windows machines menus are native controls. Because of this the `unpost` command doesn't work because tk cedes control to the system event loop in order to get platform-specific behavior.

What you want is to use instead is a toplevel window with the `overrideredirect` flag set. This lets you display a borderless window anywhere you want. The upside to this is that you aren't limited to simple text -- you can put anything you want in that toplevel -- another text widget, a canvas, buttons, etc.

Comment: Got it Bryan.  Coded and working with TopLevel.  Miss the cast shadow effect however.